# How to show all duplicate rows from Table 1 in an excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In Table1, I have several rows that is exactly the  same. Let's say I have 5 columns and 10 rows. Rows 2 and 3 are exactly alike and so is rows 8 and 9. When I Pivot table it, it only data for Rows 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10. What do I have to do so Rows 3 and 9 will also show on my Pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique identifier in your table.

You can add a column (name it "Unique ID" for example), put 1 in the first row and fill down (ensure you fill the series). You should get a sequential series (1, 2, 3, etc) will the bottom of the table.

Now if you do a new pivot table (or refresh the source data range), you can put this Unique ID in the Row Labels and you will have all the rows displayed.

Though, to be honest, I'm not quite sure why you would want that, since pivot table is used exactly to summarise and regroup similar fields, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I'm using in for our Accounts Payable. So the check number can list the same dollar amount and description but now I've added the account they are charged and that is the unique identifier.